# Date format in /var/log/cron (Oracle Linux Server 8.8)

Tags: cron, logs, text-formatting

Currently the date format in `/var/log/cron` seems to be `%b %d %H:%M:%S`, so in `/var/log/cron` I see the logs like

```
Aug 20 03:13:01 bhost1 CROND[1361808]: (user1) CMD (......)
```

Is it possible to change the format to `%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S`, so the log will be like

```
20/08/2023 03:13:01 bhost1 CROND[1361808]: (user1) CMD (......)
```